# Electrolysis of water: Which equations to use? (IB Chem)

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, water, reduction-potential

There is a list of standard electrode potentials at 298 K from the [p. 23 of IB Data Booklet 2016](https://www.ibchem.com/root_pdf/data_booklet_2016.pdf#page=27). Which of the following equations (forward/backward reactions), from the two possible ones involving the discharge of hydrogen gas and the other two with oxygen gas discharge, should I use for the oxidation and reduction of water in electrolytic cells?

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
\ce{\text{Oxidized species} <=> \text{Reduced species}} & E^⦵(\pu{V}) \\
\hline
  \begin{align}
    \ce{H2O(l) + e- &<=> 0.5 H2(g) + OH-(aq)} \\
    \ce{H+(aq) + e- &<=> 0.5 H2(g)} \\
    \ce{0.5 O2(g) + H2O(l) + 2 e- &<=> 2 OH-(aq)} \\
    \ce{0.5 O2(g) + 2 H+(aq) + 2 e- &<=> H2O(l)}
  \end{align}
&
  \begin{array}{r}
   -0.83 \\
    0.00 \\
   +0.40 \\
   +1.23
  \end{array}
\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

(Unless the use of any of these equations cannot be generalized — for a concise explanation of why this is so and what to do then I would be equally grateful.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the acidic electrolysis, use the reactions where $\ce{H+}$ occurs.

As $\ce{OH-}$ is not available in considerable amount there as a reagent, neither it is created as a product.

Generally, for a reaction choice, apply the principle of availability and stability, allowing for a reagent to exist in (relative) abundance.
$\ce{OH-}$ or anions of weak acids like $\ce{ClO-}$ do not survive in acids. Acids do not survive in hydroxides.

But note that using reactions with half of a molecule is not necessery.

$$\begin{align}
\ce{O2(g) + 4H+(aq) + 4e-  &<=> 2 H2O(l)}\\
\ce{2H+(aq) + 2e- &<=> H2(g)}
\end{align}$$

For the alkaline electrolysis, similarly, use the reactions where $\ce{OH}$- occurs.

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2 H2O(l) + 2e- &<=> H2(g) + 2 OH^-(aq)}\\
\ce{O2(g) + 2 H2O(l) + 4e- &<=> 4 OH^-(aq)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, @Poutnik. Could you also explain to me how I could apply this knowledge to, for example, the electrolysis of aqueous sodium chloride? A textbook example uses equations from both categories you mentioned.

Comment: Apply the same principle of availability and stability.

Comment: @Poutnik, I suppose that by "availability" you mean concentration of the salt, but I am not sure how to tackle "stability"... Does "stability" have to do with electrode potential values? I am too verdant to figure this out by myself.

Comment: @w_w I mean ability to survive. $\ce{OH-}$ or anions of weak acids like $\ce{ClO-}$ do not survive in acids. Acids do not survive in hydroxides. Generally, choice duch a reaction form, where reactants on both sides may exist in abundance.

Comment: I forgot to ask: If we have a neutral solution can we act and choose the equation as if we want to keep it neutral or is this not necessarily the case?

Comment: At neutral solutions it is rather arbitrary what reaction we choose, as ion equilibrium reactions cancel the difference.